# Would I get in trouble if I refresh a webpage of a country's visa appointment website every minute 24/7?

Tags: visas

Would I get in trouble if I refresh a webpage of a country's visa appointment website every minute 24/7?

If there's new opening, I'll hear a loud beep.

I'm trying to find a better appointment date :)

I did the same kind of thing to choose the courses I prefer but this might be a little different

Answer (score 3):

> Would I get in trouble if I refresh a webpage of a country's visa appointment website every minute 24/7?

No problem, 1 request/min is very light, nowhere near the DDoS laws. Check the website's ToS if you want to be extra careful, but I've never read such restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

I do not thing you get troubles, but your address may get blacklisted, and so you may not notice new appointments. I think 10 or 15 minutes would be better and less noticeable. Especially if you add also a random timeout.

I would try to avoid to get blacklisted, you may get trouble later on log-in from your computer.

Next time, try to better plan.